# Simplificar e unificar as funções em um só

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Como posso simplificar e deixar tudo em uma unica função o script abaixo?

```
var plano_0 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    plano_0.open('GET', 'buscar_valor.php?id=10', false); 
    plano_0.send(null);
    plano_0=plano_0.responseText;
    plano_0_valor=plano_0.replace(".", ",")
    arrayAmount[0]=plano_0_valor;

var plano_1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    plano_1 .open('GET', 'buscar_valor.php?id=20', false); 
    plano_1 .send(null);
    plano_1 =plano_0.responseText;
    plano_1_valor=plano_0.replace(".", ",")
    arrayAmount[1]=plano_1_valor;

var plano_2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    plano_2.open('GET', 'buscar_valor.php?id=30', false); 
    plano_2.send(null);
    plano_2=plano_0.responseText;
    plano_2_valor=plano_0.replace(".", ",")
    arrayAmount[2]=plano_2_valor;
```

Teria como fazer por exemplo:

```
function buscaValor () {
var plano = new XMLHttpRequest();
    plano.open('GET', 'buscar_valor.php?id=id_do_array', false); 
    plano.send(null);
    plano=plano.responseText;
    valor=plano.replace(".", ",")
}

arrayAmount[0]=valor_id10;
arrayAmount[1]=valor_id20;
arrayAmount[2]=valor_id30;
```

Obviamente que a função acima esta errada, mas é só um exemplo para mostrar como poderia ser.

Comment: Ao usar `false` no `plano.open` vc está dizendo que o Ajax deve ser síncrono, ou seja, o código só continuará a ser executado após uma resposta da requisição. Isso é uma prática não recomendada. O Ajax deve assíncrono, como é da sua natureza.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Primeiro cria uma variável global, que será a array mestre
var planos;

// Daí você chama a função com os ids em array
// Exemplo: fazer_plano([10,20,30]);
// A função adiciona automaticamente os valores na variável planos
// Para recuperar é só usar: planos[0]

function fazer_plano(id) {
  for (i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {
    var plano = new XMLHttpRequest();
    plano.open('GET', 'buscar_valor.php?id=' + id[i], false);
    plano.send(null);
    planos.push(plano.responseText.replace(".", ","));
  }
}
```

Nota: vale a pena dar uma olhada na documentação do [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/XMLHTTPRequest) pois no seu código podem haver erros em tempo de execução.

Comment: Muito legal sua dica, mas não consegui fazer funcionar. Existe algum meio específico para chamar a funçao com as ids? Ficou um pouco confuso essa parte para mim

Comment: Sim, você chama a função: `fazer_plano([ID_NUMERO_UM, ID_NUMERO_DOIS])`

Comment: Fiz isso, mas esta dando: TypeError: planos is undefined

Comment: Você colocou a linha `var planos;` no topo da pagina? caso ainda dê erro tente inicializar: `var planos = [];`

Comment: Agora sim, funcionou.. com relação a sua nota, nesse código também tem erros em tempo de execução?

Comment: Sim, você corre o risco de não receber a resposta a tempo por conta da conexão, o melhor seria você usar um ouvidor de eventos que tem no XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Você tem algum link onde eu possa pesquisar sobre isso pra tentar implementar nesse código?

Comment: Amigo, já está linkado na resposta. mas o que você precisa é implementar o `onreadystatechange` da sua instancia do XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Obrigado, você sabe por que recebo este aviso? `XMLHttpRequest síncrono não deve ser usado na thread principal devido a seus efeitos prejudiciais para a experiência de usuário. Para mais informações http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/`

Comment: Você tem que colocar true na ultima opção do XMLHttpRequest, ficando `plano.open('GET', SEU_URL, true)`

Comment: O aviso sumiu, mas fez a função parar de funcionar, não carregou mais os valores.

Comment: Você implementou o onreadystatechange? De uma olhada nesse link, tem uma implementação bem funcional: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82697/discussion-between-wendler-and-anderson-santos).

Comment: Fiz a implementação, te mandei o código pelo chat pra você ver como ficou. Ele só ta carregando uma ID, não descobri por que.